# Thread affinity with ReactiveUI 6

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive-programming, reactiveui

**The scenario** (WPF desktop app, .NET 4.6):

I have a listbox which display some "tasks".
The goal is to start an asynchronous process that will iterate through all tasks, executing each one of them.

It is a long running process so the desired behavior is to disable most of the  commands without locking the UI so the user can still cancel it.
It should flag each tasks as it goes (stand by, running, complete) so the UI can be dynamically updated providing feedback to end user (using styles based on the "Status" enum).

**The Problem**

When the command (`ExecuteTasks`) is executed I get the message:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

My question is: how can I get around this problem using ReactiveUI? I believe the answer is somewhere around schedulers but I couldn't figure it out so far.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
public ReactiveCommand<object> AddTask { get; }
public ReactiveCommand<object> ExecuteTasks { get; }
public IPlugin SelectedTask
{
    get { return selectedTask; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectedTask, value); }
}
public ReactiveList<IPlugin> Tasks
{
    get { return tasks; }
}
public ReactiveList<PluginFactoryGroup> TaskFactories
{
    get
    {
        return taskFactories;
    }
}

public AppViewModel(IExecutionContext context, IEnumerable<PluginFactoryGroup> taskFactories)
{

    this.context = context;

    // initialize lists
    tasks = new ReactiveList<IPlugin>() { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
    this.taskFactories = new ReactiveList<PluginFactoryGroup>(taskFactories);

    // create observables to determine whether or not commands can be executed
    var canEdit = /*...*/
    var canExecute = /*...*/

    // initialize commands
    AddTask = ReactiveCommand.Create(canEdit);
    AddTask.Subscribe(_ => {
        if (SelectedFactory != null)
        {
            var t = SelectedFactory.Create(this.context);
            Tasks.Add(t);
            SelectedTask = t;
        }
    });

    ExecuteTasks = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canExecute, _ =>
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            object result = null;
            foreach (var item in Tasks)
            {
                item.Clear();
                item.Validate();
            }

            if (Tasks.Any(e => e.Status == TaskStatus.Error))
            {
                Tasks.Reset();
                return result;
            }

            foreach (var item in Tasks)
            {
                item.Status = XrmTools.Plugins.TaskStatus.Running;
                item.Execute();
                item.Status = XrmTools.Plugins.TaskStatus.Completed;
            }
            return result;
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UI updates (ReactiveList add/remove, or IPlugin property change) need to happen in UI thread. In your case, assuming `item.Execute()` is the *lengthy* operation you want to happen in the background, you should use async/await instead of Task.Run, e.g: your code should look like:

```
ExecuteTasks = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canExecute, async _ =>
{
    object result = null;
    foreach (var item in Tasks)
    {
        item.Clear();
        item.Validate();
    }

    if (Tasks.Any(e => e.Status == TaskStatus.Error))
    {
        Tasks.Reset();
        return result;
    }

    foreach (var item in Tasks)
    {
        item.Status = XrmTools.Plugins.TaskStatus.Running;
        await ExecuteAsync(item);
        item.Status = XrmTools.Plugins.TaskStatus.Completed;
    }
    return result;
});

Task ExecuteAsync(IPlugin item)
{
    return Task.Run(() => item.Execute());
}
```

Have a look at this [reference](http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/stable/basics/reactive-command-async/) if you need more inspiration.

Comment: Fantastic. The error is gone and it works without blocking the UI as expected, thanks a lot. One thing though, the change of status - `item.status = /*new_status*/` is not signaling the UI. The collection is changing but the user interface is not. The way I got it working is by adding `Tasks.Reset()` after each change (twice) which doesn't seem right.